Geometry node : Edges of Vertex node
I would like to select edges of a specific vertex so I am using Edges of vertex node and separate geometry node . The results shows only an edges with sorting index to 0 or 1 or 2 (geometry is a cube) . Is it possible to show all the edges belong to a vertex ? if I put index node to sorting index it does not work .
Thanks for helps

This is the Blender manual entry for the Edge of Vertex node. I've never used it so I am not sure how it works with a simple cube where I assume all the edge weights are the same.

General (cumbersome) solution for any mesh
I'm suspecting Hot Knife's answer would use less nodes than mine.
Here are the steps I would do :

For each vertex, store the number of connected edges in nEdges attribute, using Edges of Vertex.
Isolate the nEdges attribute for the current vertex index as input for the loop.
Start looping nEdges times. So we are looking at one vertex, if it has 3 edges then we loop 3 times, one for each edge.
If index of the current edge is equal to the output of Edge of Vertex, then it is an edge to select.
Store this boolean value for later use.
(Optional) Add debug option to visualize the result. Here, the bigger sphere is the chosen vertex, the smaller sphere is the connected edges.

Here is the node tree :

I'm 80% sure there is a far simpler way of doing. Hopefully, this solution is somewhat understandable.
Finally, the nodes in action and the blend file :


Additionnal notes
The points 1. and 2. are only there because we can't plug the Total output of the Edge of Vertex to the Iterations input of the Repeat Zone. This part can probably be compressed but I couldn't find a better way.
Point 4. is probably as simple as we can get.

Thanks , it seems edge of vertex node it is not a complete useful node if many nodes around are necessary to complete the job

@MarcoGreco My solution is bad. Markus's one is the better way to do it.

You're starting from the wrong side. You want to select edges. Therefore start with edges, and for each edge check if either of its vertices is the vertex you're looking for:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
The "Capture Attribute" is there just so the indices are frozen and the viewer displays old indices before separation.
And here's an alternative that does need the "Capture Attribute" because it relies on attribute leaking during domain interpolations:

Imgur mirror

I knew it ! Very nice, that explains why my solution is so big.

Thanks , it seems edge of vertex node it is not a complete useful node if many nodes around are necessary to complete the job

@MarcoGreco I disagree, the node does exactly what it's supposed to do.

In my opinion the node should give the possibility to have 1 , 2 or all edges of the vertex without many additional nodes , I mean this for useful

You need to use a Repeat Node, and iterate through the Sort Index (this is the only way I've got it to work) Then store the result on the Point with an increment value on name of the Store Attribute, this way you can sort the Index of the verts - it gets a little tricky as you don't know which index belongs to which end of the Edge so you compare with the current vert index - and if it's the same then you know.

Thanks , it seems edge of vertex node it is not a complete useful node if many nodes around are necessary to complete the job
